# How do I import date and price thru phpMyAdmin to then sort correctly?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm new to MySQL and learning a lot quickly.  My main objective for learning has been to export data from one source, to import into phpMyAdmin.  The data that I first export is delivered in the following format;

```
Entry_Date - mm/dd/yyyy

Price - "123,456"
```

I would have thought to set the Fields TYPE;

```
Entry_Date type:  Date

Price type: MediumInt(10) Unsigned
```

However, as such, all dates are stored as 00-00-0000 AND price is only stored first 3 digits (up until the comma ',').

If I change the TYPE to;

```
Entry_Date type:  char(10)

Price type: varchar(10) Unsigned
```

Now value is stored properly, but the ability to sort the data is defeated, as both the date and price only SORT up until the first ' / ' and ' , ' (respectively).

**What's my move here to have the db recognize the date and price for proper SORTING, but with respect to the format in which I receive the exported data in the first place?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what is this input format, but you probably want to use [FLOAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html) type for your price and [DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html) type for your date. That way it will be sorted correctly.

You should always use proper data types for database columns. Please see [this article](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-types.html) for further learning of MySQL data types.

## Update #1

If data is specified in incorrect format that is not recognized by RDBMS then maybe it's a better approach to pre-process your input file in order to re-format it according to MySQL requirements.

But I would rather create a program to parse such an input file and to insert data to the MySQL database manually. That way you will be able to re-format all values according to needed formats.

## Update #2

It is also possible to use two columns in order to get your data into a needed format.

Create two columns:

- `date_as_char VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL` -- to hold your initial date string in the original format
- `date_as_date DATE DEFAULT NULL` -- to hold converted value

Then, insert your original string dates into the first column.

After that you can use the following query to convert data from `VARCHAR(10)` to a proper `DATE`:

```
UPDATE `table` T SET
    T.date_as_date = STR_TO_DATE(T.date_as_char, '%m/%d/%Y')
;
```

And finally you can `DROP` the first column if you want so, there is no need to store duplicate data.

Here's the **SQL fiddle** to demonstrate the solution:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88e202/1

If your data is converted as `NULL` then your initial data and specified parsing string, i.e. `%m/%d/%Y` doesn't much.

Here's the documentation for [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function.

Comment: I've tried DATE, but it does not recognize the mm/dd/yyyy format that I import. And the price will never have decimals, so I don't think FLOAT would be best. Problem with the price is that it is imported with a ',' (which I need the db to ignore).

Comment: Sorry, I thought that your prices are FLOAT numbers. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Are you familiar with this approach?

import date-values into a varchar column fake_column first, and then push them over into the real column real_columnusing STR_TO_DATE.

UPDATE tablename SET real_column = STR_TO_DATE(fake_column, '%m/%d/%Y');

In phpMyAdmin,  where do I insert such codes to creating this relationship between columns?

Comment: You don't need to create any relationships. You can just issue a SQL query that will copy data from fake column into a real one using PhpMyAdmin. After that, you can drop the fake column.

Comment: After researching all day, I've tried a lot of things. This was my best shot.  From the TABLE "SQL" tab, I ran the following code;
INSERT INTO myTable(New_Date)
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(Entry_Date,'%m/%d/%Y') as date FROM `myTable`;

I know the SELECT line will successfully convert the String to Date, however, I was not successful at inserting it into the "real" column I created New_Date. What am I missing?

Comment: First, insert all data to a table with varchar fields. Second, create new columns of required types (e.g. DATE). Then use SQL query you provided [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24431401/how-do-i-import-date-and-price-thru-phpmyadmin-to-then-sort-correctly/24431479?noredirect=1#comment37838905_24431479) to copy data from initial columns to new (normalized) ones. It should work.

Comment: That's exactly what I did.  I imported field 'Entry_Date' as a char(10),  then created another column called 'New_Date' (which automatically was populated with 0000-00-00).  Then I ran the SQL query, successfully with no error,  but that did NOT overwrite the 0000's.  :/

Comment: What was the query exactly?

Comment: UPDATE myTable SET New_Date = DATE(DATE_FORMAT(Entry_Date,'%Y-%m-%d')) ;

Comment: I've updated my answer to provide you with complete solution. I hope it will help.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!  That worked perfectly, and exactly how I need.  :)   What exactly does the "T" represent in this code?

Comment: Glad I could help ;) "T" is an alias for a table name, `table` in this case. It's not really required, but it's a good practice to use aliases in your SQL queries, especially in complex ones with multiple tables.